# Inserting a new instance to a foreign key model in django

Tags: python, django

Im new at django and new at posting so pardon my mistakes, anyways

What I have is a QR login system that will creates a new instance or record of a person scanning their qr code

the problem is that `Field 'id' expected a number but got Field 'id' expected a number but got "(insert name here)`

here is the relevant code

models.py

`````
name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Name', max_length=30,) Truck_Assigned= models.ForeignKey(Truck, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
def str(self): return self.name

class Attendance(models.Model):
name=models.ForeignKey(Helper, on_delete=models.CASCADE) attendace_time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)````

views.py
````def qrcodelogin(request):
        
        attendance=Attendance.objects.all()
        attendacecounter=attendanceCounter.objects.all()
        
        if not request.user.is_staff:
            messages.error(request, 'You are not allowed to view this page')
            return redirect('userProfile')

        if request.method == 'POST':
            try:
                with transaction.atomic():
                    name = request.POST.get('decodedText')
                    helper=Helper.objects.get(name=name)

                    attendance_log = Attendance(name=helper)
                    attendance_log.save()
                    
                    if attendanceCounter.objects.filter(name=name).exists():
                        attendanceCounter.objects.filter(name=name).update(counter=F('counter')+1)
                    else:
                        counter_log=attendanceCounter(name=name)
                        counter_log.save()
                        attendanceCounter.objects.filter(name=name).update(counter=F('counter')+1)
                    
            
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                messages.success(request, 'something went wrong')````
`````

Comment: hey Daniel, so you want to create a new Attendance record, is it?

Comment: Yes, that is the primary purpose for it

Comment: also after creating a new attendance record, the attendance counter will increment after the the record is saved

Comment: Are you sure your code is complete? Can you post image of exception or the whole error trace in the post? I ask because I don't see where you assign `id` field in the `filter()` or `get()` method.

Comment: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Cloud Strife'. 

cloud strife as a dummy name but cloud strife is already a instance in the Helper Model